# Cisco 2504 WLC setup questions

Tags: wireless-networking, wireless-access-point

I have been asked to set up a Cisco 2504 Wireless LAN Controller (WLC) but have never done so before.

I have a few quick questions that I am hoping you guys can help me with.

1. Why can't you directly connect APs to the ports on the WLC?
2. In order to set up 5 APs on the WLC must I connect the WLC to a switch first and then run Cat-5 from the switch to the APs?
3. Can I create a Captive Portal for Guest Wi-Fi Users?
4. Can I create a Guest and Internal Network Wi-Fi for guests and employees that are separated?

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes you can connect the AP direct to the ports, but you will need have a updated the firmware I don't remember the version (3 or 4 past versions) had problem with that because don't support layer 3 so you need to connect a switch between the wlc and the ap.
2. Yes
3. yes
4. Yes, the wlc at least 2504 support many ssid each one with different vlan, so the network at logical level are separated.

Comment: If you need a recently firmware for the wlc i can send you a copy, if you want to download from cisco will need a valid and active contract